# Error-Openstack Installation Cinder API did not Start

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, failed-installation, openstack-swift, openstack-cinder

I tried installing devstack OpenStack-liberty on Ubuntu 14.04 Using VM Virtualbox. I want to integrate nova,swift,cinder along with OpenStack. I have enabled services for cinder in localrc file. After trying so many times i.e stacking(run ./stack.sh) and unstacking ,I ended up getting the same error:

> 'c-api did not start'

[image]

Comment: Hello,
I have edited your question and removed a link to image. Instead, it is better to show a picture itself. :). Also, you can show error messages in quotes so it's easier to see. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your suggestion. i will do that for my next questions.

Comment: No problems. It's just a little pity nobody knows the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to resources. I was using 4GB RAM which was not sufficient. Few APIs consume more RAM while starting. Openstack Installation console waits for a while and expects APIs to start, which wasn't happening in my case due to less dedicated RAM since I was using 4GB of RAM in which only 2.5GB RAM was given to my VM.

After struggling few days I got to know the issue and upgraded my system's RAM to 8GB, and it worked!
So I suggest people who want to work with Openstack-Swift and Openstack-Neutron should dedicate minimum of 5.5GB to VM!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (only 4GB RAM) in an old laptop. My solution was to modify the variable $SERVICE_TIMEOUT to 160 in the /devstack/stackrc file.